How does Electro-Optic Phase Modulation cause individual photons to change frequency?
I noticed that similar questions were asked in the past, however, no clear answer has been given to the particle-level mechanisms involved here. I understand that Electro-Optical Phase Modulation changes the refractive index of the material, and this change modulates the phase of the optical signal to create new frequencies around the central one. However, what happens on the particle level?
Assume you have several photons of some frequency $\omega_c$ traveling inside a medium with a refractive index $n_0$. Then the medium experiences a change in the refractive index that is time-dependent $n(t) = n_0 + \Delta n(t)$. What does this mean for the individual photons?
Here are links to the similar questions I found:
How does optical phase modulation produce photons with different frequencies?
Do sidebands corresponds to real photons at that frequency?

A good 3blue1brown video that describes things classically is But why would light "slow down"? | Optics puzzles 3. It doesn't answer your question, but it is great background. Additional videos referenced in this one might go further.
